# Reflection considers properties to have different values despite them appearing equal

Tags: c#, reflection

I have 2 types:

```
public class TypeA
{
    public int SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
public class TypeB
{
    public int SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

If I create an instance of both types, and in both cases give 'SomePropety' a value of 3, I can retrieve the values of these properties with reflection:

```
var aProperty = a.GetType().GetProperties().Single(p => p.Name == "SomeProperty");
var bProperty = b.GetType().GetProperties().Single(p => p.Name == "SomeProperty");

var aValue = aProperty.GetValue(a);
var bValue = bProperty.GetValue(b);
```

Here `aValue` and `bValue` now have the value of 3.

But I'm finding that when I compare these raw values, C# does not consider them equal:

```
if (aValue != bValue)
{
    //this code is hit
}
```

I look in the debugger and both are clearly '3'. I've never actually encountered this before, have I walked into some scenario where C# considers them unequal because they came from different properties even though they're a raw data type?

Comment: You're using `!=` to compare two objects. This does a reference equality test. You've got two integers which have the same value, but they've both been boxed, and the boxes have different addresses, so the reference equality check fails. Use e.g. `Equals(aValue, bValue)`, or unbox them before comparing (`int a = (int)aValue; int b = (int)bValue; if (a == b) { ... }`)

Comment: Thank you, to help my understanding could you please elaborate on why they've been 'boxed'? Normally this comparison would be fine for ints of course.

Comment: `PropertyInfo.GetValue` returns `object`. `object` is a heap-allocated thing, and a variable of type `object` contains the address of the object. `int` is a value type, and isn't stored on the heap: a variable of type `int` just contains the value of the int. In order to have a variable of type `object` refer to an `int`, the `int` needs be placed inside a special heap-allocated object (the "box"). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing

Comment: Perfect - thank you!